# Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "xml" - Acid/Clean project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javabeans

I am using Spring 4.1.6 (I chose to overide the spring-core - a part of Dependency Management - by choosing to work with Spring 4.1.6 andnot Spring 3.2.0 - see attached picture), Hibernate 4.3 and Tomcat 7/JRE 1.7

It would be nice to know what combination of products works successfully on Tomcat7. I know that Tomcat 7/JRE 1.7 is not the latest/greatest but I need it for some software I am working with. I have ran Maven->Clean and Maven->Install several times.

The error I am getting is:

> SPECIAL NOTE! AN ERROR HAS OCURRED
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 11 in XML document from file
>   [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\WEB-INF\dbcontext.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 89; Document root element "beans", must
>   match DOCTYPE root "xml".

I have attached:

- pom.xml
- Spring Configuration File (dbcontext.xml)
- Program I am trying
  run
- log file (I trimmed some of it off)

How can I get past this issue?

TIA

**UPDATE**
I have been finding out that the problem could be due to a mis-match of versions (spring and perhaps hibernate). Is there a way to an "acid clean" of the project so I can test this theory? Some kind of command that gets rid of everything - or - can I export the project and import it to a different directory?

**overwriting managed spring-core**

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.apostx.contractorsclub</groupId>
    <artifactId>fieldwork-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Product Service</name>
    <description>Product REST Service</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>fieldwork-server</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Spring Configuration File(dbcontext.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactorybean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.apostx.ccfd.master.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.isolation">${hibernate.isolation}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">${hibernate.transaction.factory_class}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="MstrauthorizationsDataImpl" class="com.apostx.ccfd.master.dao"/>

</beans>
```

**Program I am trying to run**

```
package com.apostx.ccfd.master.main;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.apostx.ccfd.master.dao.MstrauthorizationsDataImpl;

public class TestOracleHibernateAddData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                
        try {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();  
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "classpath*:**/dbcontext.xml") ;

        MstrauthorizationsDataImpl dao = 
                ctx.getBean("MstrauthorizationsDataImpl", MstrauthorizationsDataImpl.class);

        System.out.println("the answer is " + 
                dao.getAuthorizaions( new String("5"), "test@me.com", "1234567"));

        ctx.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception  e ) {
            System.out.println("SPECIAL NOTE! AN ERROR HAS OCURRED " + e);
            System.exit(-11);
        }
    }
}
```

**log file**

```
0 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
15 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
31 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@58e38fae: startup date [Sun Jul 02 18:05:39 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
69 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
69 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
69 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment  - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in directory tree [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master\dao] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master\dto] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master\entities] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master\main] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\com\apostx\ccfd\master\webservices] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Searching directory [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\WEB-INF] for files matching pattern [C:/WORK/Software/SOAPUI/extract-rest-with-crud/productws/target/classes/**/dbcontext.xml]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/annotations-api.jar]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/catalina-ant.jar]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/catalina-ha.jar]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/catalina-tribes.jar]
185 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/catalina.jar]
200 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar]
216 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/el-api.jar]
216 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/jasper-el.jar]
216 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/jasper.jar]
231 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/jsp-api.jar]
231 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/servlet-api.jar]
231 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-api.jar]
231 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar]
247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/ApacheTomcat7/install/lib/tomcat-util.jar]
    269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/xml-resolver-1.2.jar]
269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar]
269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.0.3/cxf-core-3.0.3.jar]
269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.1.0/xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.0.3/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.3.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-wsdl/3.0.3/cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.3.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.3/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.0.3/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.3.jar]
284 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.10-b140310.1920/jaxb-impl-2.2.10-b140310.1920.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.2.10-b140310.1920/jaxb-core-2.2.10-b140310.1920.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/3.0.3/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/3.0.3/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/3.0.3/cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/3.0.3/cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/neethi/neethi/3.0.3/neethi-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/3.0.3/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-search/3.0.3/cxf-rt-rs-extension-search-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs/3.0.3/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.3.jar]
300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar]
369 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar]
369 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar]
369 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10.Final.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar]
385 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar]
400 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar]
400 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar]
428 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar]
429 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar]
431 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar]
433 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/Users/dgmufasa/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar]
436 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/Java%20JDK/install/JRE7.0/lib/ext/dns_sd.jar]
436 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/Java%20JDK/install/JRE7.0/lib/ext/jaccess.jar]
437 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Looking for matching resources in jar file [file:/C:/WORK/Software/Java%20JDK/install/JRE7.0/lib/ext/localedata.jar]
```

Comment: remove the `<!DOCTYPE` line.

Comment: Thanks - that was it